# Choose the right data structure for my algorithm in java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Today i need to choose the most efficent data structure for my needs in java.
Basically i have an algorithm that have a set of `<Integer, Object>`.

- First multiple thread create some of this set, than they get merged,
  sorted by the Integer and removed eventual duplicate Object in the
  result set.
- Than for each element x `<Integer, Object>` 
  I need to
  Obtain the y elements with Integer less than x.Integer

Since the second point is the relevant in the algorithm which data structure would you choose to use in Java?

Comment: Clarification request: when we have `(i1, o1)` and `(i2, o2)`, they are considered duplicates if ... ? Depending on the answer, the usual `Set` (`TreeSet` or `HashSet`) of the pairs, or `Map <Integer, Object>`, might suffice.

Comment: A `TreeSet` or `TreeMap` will allow to order by `Integer`. Then selecting the required elements is just iterating the container from the start. If you need faster (e.g., split them into a separate container), please state that clearly in the question.

Comment: @Gassa if(o1.equals(o2)), by the way if this is true even the integer it's the same, but if(i1 == i2) you can't tell if the object are the same

Comment: Regarding to the second question i didn't undestand it. Can u be more clear, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `NavigableMap` such as `TreeMap` or `ConcurrentSkipListMap`

Note: `TreeMap` is not thread safe,  however is likely to be more efficient if you collect the data for each thread in a local copy of the TreeMap and merge the results when finished. i.e. you can have much lower contention.

Note2: You only need a `TreeMap` for performing the `less than` comparison.  A further improvement might be to use `HashMap` to collect the data in each thread, and merge the results into a `TreeMap` to perform the searchs.

Comment: thread safety is not a problem till now, i'll do exactly the same you said to avoid it.
I will surrelly use a simple hashMap to collect the result from the thread and than merge them into the desidered Map.

I will now take a look into the documentation for TreeMap to see if it fits well from my problem, if so i'll mark the answer.

Thanks for your time.